# Closure of divisibility in denumerator, under sum of fractions

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, rational-numbers

I have to prove that for a fixed positive integer n, the subset A of Q consisting of rationals with denumerator that divide n under addition, forms a group under addition.

I just did that it's not empty ( 0/1 is in A and is its identities ), and also that if we begin choosing q1,q2 with denumator that divides n,  we have q1= a/(n/k1) = k1a/n  and q2 = b/(n/k2) = k2b/n      for a,b integers and k1,k2 divisors of n.    Then, its clear that q1 - q2 has a denumator that divides n because    k1a/n   -  k2b/n    =  (k1a - k2b)/n   has a denumator that divides n, and by the subgroup criteria,  it forms a subgroup.

So that should prove it ? did i make any mistake  ?

I'm thinking that because i've seen two proofs of that same problem but they seem to go a bit more complex , they go :
Being q1= a/c   and q2 = b/t      where c and t divides n, we can see that if d = gcd(c,t) , then we can write the denumerators  c,t  of q1 and q2  as c = d.k1     and   t d.k2.    So,   q1 - q2 =   a/(dk1) -  b/(dk2)      =     (a.d.k2 - b.k1.d )/ (d²k1k2)       =      (ak2 - bk1)/(dk1k2)    =      (ak2 - bk2)/lcm(c,t)     and hence stating that  if c and t divide n,  lcm(c,t) also divides n .

I'm just wondering if i did something wrong, because my proof sounds so more simple.

Also, theres something i'm really suspicious of,  why could they replace  dk1k2 with lcm(dk1, dk2) = lcm(c,t) ??  I worked out that empirically, and   lcm(ka,kb) = k.a.b  only when  a and b are relatively prime, but generally it should be  lcm (ka,kb) = k.lcm(a,b).

Thanks a lot in advance
Thanks a lot

Comment: The idea of your argument is better. There is some awkwardness of exposition.

Comment: There is a possible subtlety which might call for more to be said. Does "denonominator" denote *any* possible denominator, or the *least* possible denominator, or a denominator that is coprime to the numerator?

Comment: I guess any possible denominator. It's an exercise from Foote Dummit , specifically 2.1.c

Comment: André, its exactly that awkwardness i'm trying to improve. I have engineering background and started delving into pure mathematics just very recently, so a lot of room to improve.All tips are welcome ! :)

Comment: What is the source of the "more complex" proof?

Comment: http://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/01/23/decide-whether-or-not-a-given-subset-of-a-group-is-a-subgroup/  here , third question. Really complete site by the way with Dummit exercises.

Comment: And the other proof source i have in PDF

Comment: The answer to your edit comes from the identity $\,{\rm lcm}(c,t) = ct/\gcd(c,t).\,$ Therefore writing $\,q_1-q_2 = (at-bc)/(ct)\,$  then canceling $\,\gcd(c,t)\,$ from the top and bottom yields $\,{\rm lcm}(c,t)\,$ on the bottom.

Comment: Oh, i'm verifying empirically that it seems that for a,b integers, if  d=gcd(a,b)     and  a=dk1 , b=dk2      then k1 and k2 are relatively prime . So, thats why we had that lcm(dk1,dk2) = dk1k2 .. just because d was their gcd and made k1,k2 be relatively prime. Is that true ?

Comment: Thinking about it more, I suspect that "denominator" denotes the *least* denominator. So one needs to say more than your proof, since it yields only that $\,q_1-q_2\,$ can be written with denominator $\,n,\,$ not that its least denominator divides $\,n.\,$ To conclude the latter from the former requires knowing that the least denominator divides every denominator, a fact that is equivalent to the *Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic* (the nontrivial part, i.e. *uniqueness* of prime factorizations)

Comment: However, since D&F is groups-first (not rings-first), and this is an exercise on verifying the subgroup property, I don't think that they intended the reader to have to investigate these ring-theoretic subtleties at this point. So I think it is fine to interpret their definition of the set $A$ as those rationals that can be written with *some* denominator that divides $\,n,\,$ in which case your proof is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help Bill :)